# SharePoint Online List alerts to USers and SharePoint Online support team

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-developer

When new Item is added to the SharePoint online list SharePoint support team should recieve an email and user should receive and alert.

Could you please share the details step by step for SharePoint Online site--> List

If you have any queries please let us know?

Thanks,
Santhosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your organization is using Office 365 E1/E3/E5 licensing model then you will have "Power Automate for Office 365" available for you to use. Using this product you can trigger automated emails whenever new items are created in your SharePoint online list.

[image]

[image]

Please check [this Technet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37070.microsoft-flow-send-customized-email-when-new-sharepoint-list-item-is-added.aspx) which describes it in details. You can then add 'To', 'CC' and 'BCC' fields to include your intended recipients.

[image]

[This is a post from Powerusers forum](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Send-an-email-when-a-new-item-is-created-in-Sharepoint-define/td-p/109087) which puts some detail around it as well.

If you can't user Power automate, then you might have to think about using **SharePoint workflows** for this task.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to flows, there are two following options.

1.Set alert in the list.
[image]
2.Create a workflow associated with the list. Start option is set as "Start workflow automatically when an item is created".
[image]